# C# background worker freezes UI when running a 2nd time

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

In my UI, when a press a button, the following code is executed:

```
backgroundWorker1 = new BackgroundWorker();
backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);
backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted);
backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
```

This works great the first time. When I hit the button (which then becomes disabled), I can still move the window around and click stuff while the background task is executing. But when the background worker is done (button becomes enabled again) and I press it again, the background worker runs, but I no longer have control of the window.

I have no idea why this doesn't work the second time. Is there something I need to do before or after the background worker runs to make sure it is not blocking the UI thread?

Thanks!

**Edit:** In the backgroundworker ProgressChanged handler, I update a progress bar and text labels displaying how far along the background worker is. They are constantly updated and never freeze. But when I try and drag the window or click on other controls, they only respond periodically.

The backgroundworker accesses an instance of a class that is a global variable in the UI thread. The idea was to instantiate the object, run a long function the object performs from inside the backgroundworker's DoWork, and then access the object after the backgroundworker has finished to view the results. Is this ok to do?

Inside this object's function that is called in the backgroundworker's DoWork, a couple static classes are accessed. Will this cause any sort of threading issues?

Comment: Call `Dispose()` on the `backgroundWorker` when you're finished with it.

Comment: There doesn’t appear to be anything wrong with your code. Could you paste the event handlers for `ProgressChanged` and `RunWorkerCompleted`?

Comment: @Killercam: It’s not trivial to call `Dispose` correctly on a `BackgroundWorker`.

Comment: I wonder why are people up-voting this question when there's no clear way to reproduce.

Comment: In your worker thread are you only interacting with GUI controls via Invoke?  That's the only thing that comes to mind that would affect the GUI in this way. Maybe improper GUI control access is getting the worker & GUI thread(s) tangled up?

Comment: I don't have to use invoke in the ProgressChanged function right? Do I need to use invoke in the RunWorkerCompleted?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `BackgroundWorker` in two ways.

1. By dropping it from the toolbox to the form and setting its properties and events in the properties window.
2. By defining it programmatically.

Probably you mixed both approaches.

---

If you used the first approach, then drop all the initialization code (the form does it automatically for you!) and call only

```
backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
```

---

If you want to use the second approach, do **not** place it on the form. Instead declare it as member variable. The only purpose of being able to add it as a component to the form is to enable setting properties and events through the properties window. The `BackgroundWorker` does not need anything from the form and can be used completely independently from any form. Then setup the worker in the forms constructor

```
backgroundWorker1 = new BackgroundWorker();
backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged +=
    new ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);
backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted +=
    new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted);
```

and do only this in the button click handler

```
backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
```

---

The same considerations are true for most or all of the components that you find in the toolbox in the `Components` section.

Answer (score 0):

if possible try to use [Reactive extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx)...
its awesome for asynchronous processing.